# Glassfish hooks

Tags: glassfish, hook

Does Glassfish has any hooks for start and shutdown and for domain start/stop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these are called [Lifecycle Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beamc/index.html) and are Glassfish-specific.

Events that are supported are: `INIT_EVENT, STARTUP_EVENT, READY_EVENT, SHUTDOWN_EVENT, or TERMINATION_EVENT`.

Comment: Do you know if there are any for domain startup or shutdown ?

Comment: Glassfish is started/stopped per-domain. There is no "global" start/stop, only domain start/stop.

Comment: Yap, thanks, that was a stupid question... i did not think enough about that part. :D

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking at this now, this may also help: http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/startup_and_shutdown_events_with